# reached end of file while parsing, cannot find missing bracket

Tags: java, compiler-errors, curly-braces

So I know this error is when there is a bracket missing, but I have checked and this code works in IntelliJ, so any ideas what else might be causing it or am I just so blind :(

```
class Solution {

static int B;
static int H;
static boolean flag = true;
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

static {
    
    int B = scanner.nextInt();
    int H = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();

    try {
        if (B <= 0 || H <= 0) {
            flaf = false;
            throw new Exception ("java.lang.Exception: Breadth and height must be positive");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    if(flag){
        int area=B*H;
        System.out.print(area);
    }
    
}//end of main

}//end of class
```

Comment: It is a good file, there is nothing wrong (except for missing import statements). Where did you see the error? And what exactly did it say?

Comment: A typo in your try-catch `flaf` should be `flag`.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets look fine.

One error I see is a typo.

if (B <= 0 || H <= 0) {
flaf = false;

instead of flag, you typed "flaf".

I copied an ran your code in eclipse it runs fine.